# Is Spring NamedParameterJdbcTemplate transaction-aware?

Tags: java, spring, transactions, spring-jdbc

I'm building an application in which I want to use Spring JDBC for data base access and I'm trying to decide if I should use `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` or `TransactionTemplate` for that.

The documentation for `TransactionTemplate` says:

> Template class that simplifies programmatic transaction demarcation and
>     transaction exception handling.
>
> The central method is #execute, supporting transactional code that
>     implements the TransactionCallback interface. This template handles
>     the transaction lifecycle and possible exceptions such that neither the
>     TransactionCallback implementation nor the calling code needs to explicitly
>     handle transactions.

but for `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` it only says:

> Template class with a basic set of JDBC operations, allowing the use
>     of named parameters rather than traditional '?' placeholders.
>
> This class delegates to a wrapped #getJdbcOperations() JdbcTemplate
>     once the substitution from named parameters to JDBC style '?' placeholders is
>     done at execution time.

Does this mean that if I configure a transaction manager in my app even with that I will not get rollbacks on failure if I use `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate`

If it doesn't what is then the difference between those two classes and what should I have in account to choose one over the other?

Answer (score 0):

I have used **NamedParameterJdbcTemplate** and it work perfectly fine in production environment. It has advantage over using **JdbcTemplate**.

If have used both way, by defining own transaction proxy and boundaries using using **XML based** configuration, and with @**Transaction** annotation.